# Probability of choosing a cell in a $ N\times M$ grid with specific conditions

Tags: combinatorics

I have this problem :
Given a $N\times M$ grid.
You cover $2$ cells by a $1\times2$ tile.
If you pick a cell,what is the probability for it to be covered by the tile?
It's not hard to evaluate the number of the tile possible positions, which is $N(M-1)$.
But how could I find the answer ?

Comment: What is being chosen at random here? The tile placement, the cell you pick, or both? And is it being done uniformly from all possibilities, or in a different way?

Comment: The tile placement and the choice of the cell are both done randomly and with uniform possibilites

Answer (score 1):

For any fixed tile placement, the probability is $\frac{2}{MN}$ that a randomly chosen cell is covered by the tile. There are $2$ cells covered, out of $MN$ cells total.

Since this is true no matter where the tile is placed, it is still true when the tile is placed randomly.

(Note, though, that once you pick a cell, the probability that a randomly placed tile will cover it can vary. Corner and edge cells are less likely to be covered by a tile. That's not relevant for this problem, but I'm mentioning it for completeness.)

Comment: Isn't a corner less likely to be covered than an interior square? ($2$ ways for a corner; $4$ ways for an interior square).

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Let :

- T the random variable in {0,1} that determines if we choose a tile (C=1).
- I is a random variable in $\{(i,j)/ (i,j) \in [1,N] \times [1,M-1]\}$ that determines the Initial position of the left tile in the board.

$$p(T=1) = \sum_{i=1, j=1}^{i=N, j=M-1} p(T=1 | I = (i,j))p(I=(i,j))$$

With :

- Given the possible initial positions : $p(I=(i,j)) = \frac{1}{N(M-1)}$
- Because we have 2 tiles covered, then : $p(T=1 | I = (i,j)) = \frac{2}{N \cdot M}$

So, $p(T=1) = \frac{2}{N \cdot M}$